# How to operate correctly on matrices with unknown outer dimensions in cython: review of working code

Tags: python, cython, numpy-ndarray

I'm using cython to interface with functions in an existing C library that operate on 2x2 matrices.  When given additional dimensions, I want to apply the function on each inner matrix following the tiling behavior of other numpy functions such as nympy.linalg.inv.

The following code (based partially on numpy.linalg and partially on some earlier posts here) already does what I want:

mylib.pxd:

```
cdef extern from "mylib.h":
    void convert_xtoy(const double complex (*x)[2], double complex (*y)[2])
    void convert_ytox(const double complex (*y)[2], double complex (*x)[2])
```

mylib.pyx:

```
from mylib cimport convert_xtoy
from mylib cimport convert_ytox
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

#
# fn2x2: pointer to function taking two double complex [2][2] arrays
#
ctypedef void (*fn2x2)(const double complex (*)[2], double complex (*)[2])

#
# helper2x2: call fn on each 2x2 array in input
#
cdef helper2x2(fn2x2 fn, name, arrays):
    #
    # If we were passed a single argument, then there will be an
    # extraneous outer dimension.  Remember to remove it.
    #
    flatten = len(arrays) == 1

    #
    # Convert the input arrays to C compatible double complex form,
    # validate that the last two dimensions are 2x2, and create the
    # output array with same shape as input.
    #
    input = np.asarray(arrays, dtype=np.complex128, order="C")
    if input.ndim < 2 or input.shape[-2] != 2 or input.shape[-1] != 2:
        raise ValueError(name + ": expected 2x2 array")
    output = np.empty(input.shape, dtype=np.complex128, order="C")

    #
    # Create views into the input and output arrays that flatten
    # all but the two inner dimensions.
    #
    vin = input.view()
    vin.shape = (-1, 2, 2)
    vout = output.view()
    vout.shape = (-1, 2, 2)

    #
    # Call fn on each 2x2 array...
    #
    cdef np.ndarray[double complex, ndim=2] cvin
    cdef np.ndarray[double complex, ndim=2] cvout
    for i in range(vin.shape[0]):
        vin2x2 = vin[i, :, :]
        vin2x2.shape = (2, 2)
        cvin = vin2x2
        vout2x2 = vout[i, :, :]
        vout2x2.shape = (2, 2)
        cvout = vout2x2
        fn(<const double complex (*)[2]>cvin.data,
                <double complex (*)[2]>cvout.data)

    #
    # If we added an extraneous dimension, remove it.
    #
    if flatten:
        return output[0]
    else:
        return output

#
# xtoy: convert from x to y
#
def xtoy(*arrays):
    return helper2x2(&convert_xtoy, "xtoy", arrays)

#
# ytox: convert from y to x
#
def ytox(*arrays):
    return helper2x2(&convert_ytox, "ytox", arrays)
```

It's doing exactly what I intended: if xtoy or ytox is given a 2x2 matrix, it returns a 2x2 result.  If given multiple 2x2 matrix arguments in the call, it returns an n x 2 x 2 matrix where n is the number of arguments.  If given a higher dimension matrix, it tiles over the outer dimensions and returns a matrix of same shape as the original.

But to do this, helper2x2 had to create a view into the input and output matrices, then a view into slices of those views, then the C compatible views.  It seems like a lot of steps.

My question is: is there a cleaner way to do this?  Or am I already doing it "right"?  Any other constructive review comments on the code will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, so it could (probably does) have mistakes in it, but:

- I'd start by getting it into a view that Cython understands as far out as possible (i.e. not in the loop). This'll make slice a lot faster. Essentially each time you assign to `cvin` and `cvout` a reasonable amount of checking has to happen, and we can make sure it only happens once. I've used typed memoryviews instead of `ndarray` for the example, but they should both work and do very similar things:

  ```
  # Note that I've specified this as C-contiguous. You rely on
  # this later so we may as well let Cython enforce it
  cdef complex double[:, :, ::1] cy_vout
  cdef complex double[:, :, ::1] cy_vin

  # ...

  # just after "vout.shape = (-1, 2, 2)"
  cy_vout = vout
  cv_vin = vin
  ```
- I think most of your loop body can be dropped. You certainly shouldn't need to assign the shape as `(2, 2)`
- I get the pointer by the location of the first element of the array instead of `.data`. This avoids casting (which is always a good thing since casts often hide errors).

  ```
  fn(&cy_vin[i, :, :], &cy_vout[i, :, i])
  ```

  I think in your case you probably still need the cast to get it into an array pointer instead of just an element pointer, but even so I think this is clearer.

Assuming no mistakes that could be quicker and simpler.

Comment: This was helpful -- loop is much cleaner now.  See code in my answer...

Answer (score 0):

Changed the middle two blocks as follows.  It's cleaner than the original code.

```
    #
    # Create views into the input and output arrays that flatten
    # the outer dimensions.
    #
    vin = input.view()
    vin.shape = (-1, 2, 2)
    vout = output.view()
    vout.shape = (-1, 2, 2)
    cdef double complex [:, :, :] cvin  = vin
    cdef double complex [:, :, :] cvout = vout

    #
    # Call fn on each 2x2 array...
    #
    cdef int i
    for i in range(vin.shape[0]):
        fn(<const double complex (*)[2]>&cvin[i, 0, 0],
                <double complex (*)[2]>&cvout[i, 0, 0])
```